# CentOS: MySQL ERRNO 28

Tags: mysql, centos, errno

for several days I have a problem with my server. Once I create a table, I get the error: ERRNO 28.

I think it says that there is no more memory available.

Now I have entered this via terminal: df-h

Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/ dev/sdb2 1.4T 1.3T 0 100% /
/ dev/sdb1 494m 13M 456M 3% / boot
tmpfs 7.8 G G 0 7.8 0% / dev / shm

As you can see there is no more free space. Now I have cleared my log files, tmp files and deleted unnecessary files (total amount of 500GB). Then there was about 500 GB available on my server but just for 10-20 seconds. After that there was again 0% space available.

The I have executed the following command: -sh /*

and here the result:
12K /aquota.group
12K /aquota.user
5,9M /bin
11M /boot
8,0K /buser
136K /dev
6,0M /etc
41M /extra
80K /home
212M /lib
19M /lib
64
16K /lost+found
4,0K /media
4,0K /mnt
4,0K /mv
4,0K /opt
0 /proc
60K /root
28M /sbin
4,0K /selinux
4,0K /srv
0 /sys
4,0K /tmp
559M /usr
9,3G /var
5,8G /www

Now if you add all these together you will see that it cant be full.

Does anyone hav any idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Did you checked this http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-error-28-and-solution/

you need to check all filesystems where MySQL operates

Hope it will solve